# QML: StackView and C++ bound variables

Tags: c++, qml, components, qt5

With Qt5.7, I use a StackView to switch among several `QML Objects`:

```
StackView {
    id: stack
    anchors.fill: parent
    initialItem: initObj
}

Component {
    id: initObj
    ModuleHome {}
}

Component {
    id: obj1
    Module1 {}
}

// ...

stack.push({item: item, replace: true, destroyOnPop: true})
```

where `item` is i.e. `obj1`.
It works and I can easily add an animation for the transitions.

The problem is inside my objects.
Some of them have some variables bound to C++, that I use to update the UI, i.e.:

```
property int itemSize: MyClass.itemSize
onItemSizeChanged {
    // do something
}
```

Before migrate to `StackView` all the my objects were created on startup and they were "alive", therefore they were listening to the changes of `itemSize`.
Now they listen only when they are visible, so they don't do the "something" I need because the changes have likely already happened (i.e. I read from settings file on startup).

One solution is to call a C++ method in the `Component.onCompleted` event to request the last update of the vars. It will work, but I will loose the benefits of the bound vars.

Is there any other smart way? I.e. force automagically the update of the bound variables on component load.

Comment: Set the values of the vars inside the `Component.onCompleted` event seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases you should not need the `Component.onCompleted`-event.
If you need it, you would most likely have been in need of it already when you did not use the `StackView`.

Why? Because the probabillity is high, that you might refactor your code, in a way that you use bindings, rather than signal-handeling.
Of course, this might not be possible in any case, but (without proof) I would guess a number of 99% of cases where you did not need the `Component.onCompleted`-event should be possible to be refactored.

If you use the signal-handlers to set variables, (including the `Component.onCompleted`-signal) it tends to become more and more *non-declarative*, which you might try to avoid.

Setting the properties in event-handlers such as `Component.onCompleted` usually don't bind (unless you use `Qt.binding(function() {return value})` which might lead to further issues.

Instead, if you need to react to a `valueChanged`-signal, consider triggering this in the `Component.onCompleted` manually, rather than initializing the value there, to avoid errors due to forgotten bindings.

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    somePropertyChanged()
    someOtherPropertyChanged()
    ......
}
```

But again: The first thin you should try, is to solve the problems by replacing the event-handling by binding (*conditionaly*) directly to the values.

Comment: This makes sense! Looking deeper at my code, I think the mistake was to take advantage of the binding when the variables are not initialized yet. Therefore the first time I set them the `valueChanged` signal is fired. Instead I need to rely upon their actual value and use that signal just to update the UI.